# Explicit Broadcast receiver dont launch if app is killed in android oreo and earlier

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I need help with my clock alarm app.
I have declared a Broadcast Receiver to trigger a clock alarm

Manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".view.broadcastreceivers.ClockAlarmReceiver"/>
```

class ClockAlarmReceiver.kt

```
class ClockAlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
  override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        alarm = intent?.getStringExtra(ALARM_VIEW_EXTRA)?.let { fromJson<Alarm>(it) }!!
        Log.d("ClockAlarmReceiver ", "Received $alarm")
   }
}
```

I launch the pending intent in this way

```
...

 val alarmPendingIntent = Intent(context, ClockAlarmReceiver::class.java).let { intent ->
            intent.putExtra(ALARM_VIEW_EXTRA, alarm.toJson())
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, alarmId.toInt(), intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            )
        }
        val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        alarmManager.setExact(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            targetTime.timeInMillis,
            alarmPendingIntent
        )
...
```

These are my sdk configs

```
    'compileSdk': 29,
    'minSdk'    : 21,
    'targetSdk' : 29
```

It is working well on android 9.0 and 10 but In 8 and previous versions is not working when the app is killed

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Something to add here is when the app is in memory in all versions is working well

Comment: What do you mean by "when the app is killed"? Did you use "force stop" on the app from the settings?

Comment: Also, what device(s) are you testing on?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @DavidWasser when I say the app is killed is when is removed from Android's Multitasking Drawer, or is removed by the OS from background.
I have tested in pixel 2 emulator, also nexus 5x and pixel 3a

Comment: Sorry, I don't see anything wrong. Strange. Hope you find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hey if someone is having the same issue I found 2 things:
1. the Alarmanager was the thing that never triggered when the app was closed
2. This behavior only occurs when the app is in debug, I don't know why but when I created the release version it worked well

Comment: Hey, I am also facing the same issue have you find any solution. even in android 9.0. can you please point it out if you find any than

Answer (score 1):

As mention in the [android developer docs](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms), the Alarm manager will not work in doze mode or when the app is sleeping, and if you need to ensure that your work completes even when the device is idle then use - setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() instead of set() with alarm manager.
example--

```
(USE)
alarmMgr.setExactAndAllowWhilwIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60 * 1000, alarmIntent);

(DON'T USE)- 
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60 * 1000, alarmIntent);
```